# How to link values in sql

Tags: sql

Ok so I have a dummy question for sql.
I have product abc and warehouse 1
How do i make the value look like: abc-1
I tried to do 'and', &, but it doesn't work out.
Sorry if this is a dummy question.

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL or SQL Server, you can use the **`CONCAT`** function. Use an expression like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(t.product,'-',t.warehouse) AS foo
  FROM mytable t
```

For Oracle, you can use the double pipe characters for string concatenation:

```
SELECT t.product||'-'||t.warehouse AS foo
  FROM mytable t
```

For SQL Server, you also have the option of using the **`+`** operator for string concatenation, if the operands are string types and not numeric types.

Comment: This is fine, but let's not confuse a newbie by using a table alias unnecessarily.

Comment: ...and what's the advantage when using `+` works on the above platforms as well?

Comment: @Alvin Thompson: The **`+`** operator doesn't perform string concatenation in MySQL, Oracle or Postgres; That only "works" in SQL Server. The problem with Oracle `CONCAT` function is that only takes two arguments. To use CONCAT in Oracle to perform equivalent, you'd need e.g. `CONCAT(CONCAT(t.product,'-'),t.warehouse)`

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. In that case, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the '+' operator.

select product_name + '-' + cast(warehousenumber as varchar) as joined from table

Comment: Do you need the cast if you start with a string?  Genuinely not sure.

Comment: In the example you provided above, I assumed that the 1 was stored as an int or other numeric data type. If it starts as a character data type, no cast is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

USE CONCAT(ColumnName, '-', ColumnName) or you can also use simple + sign like columnName + '-' + columnName but make sure you check isnull for each column when you use +